# How can a param be added to boot-command but not accepted by sysctl?

Tags: linux, boot, kernel

I can successfully add `libata.ignore_hpa=1` to my boot command and the following cmd will yield a '1' upon boot:

`cat /sys/module/libata/parameters/ignore_hpa`

but grep'ing `sysctl -a` for libata and attempting `sysctl -w libata.ignore_hpa=1`result in failure.

How can a param be added to boot-command but not accepted by sysctl??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two different interfaces for accessing and controlling module information. `/sys` uses the interfaces exposed my `sysfs`, but this is - actually - not what is controlled by `sysctl`. The latter accesses stuff under `/proc/sys`.